# Can you access multiple firebase firestore databases in a flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

On this web page, it says that you can now have multiple Firestore databases in a google cloud project.
[cloud.google.com](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/manage-multiple-firestore-databases-in-a-project)
Does this also mean that you can access multiple Firestore databases in a single Flutter app?  If so, are there any docs that explain how to do this e.g. what does the firebase_options.dart file have in it and does the Flutterfire CLI tool allow you to set up access to more than one Firestore database.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** 2023-10-25

Now [we have the ability](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11414#issuecomment-1729296707) to connect to a non-default database.

---

> Does this also mean that you can access multiple Firestore databases in a single Flutter app?

When it comes to Android, starting with [Cloud Firestore version 24.7.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#firestore_v24-7-0), it:

> Exposed multi-database support for Cloud Firestore.

This means that we can have multiple Firestore database instances in a single project. However, I cannot see this option in [Flutter](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore-class.html) yet. You can only create an instance by calling [FirebaseFirestore.instance](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore/instance.html) or by calling by calling [FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore-class.html).

So in my opinion it's a matter of time until we'll get the same option in Flutter too.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. will be waiting for update

Answer (score 3):

*firebaser here*

Good catch! It looks like the ability to connect to a non-default database isn't in our Flutter SDKs yet. I just filed [issue #11414](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11414) on the GitHub repo for it, so follow that to check on its status.

**Update**: This feature is available in [SDK version 4.9.0](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#cloud_firestore---v490) and later (since late August 2023). You can pass the database ID as the second argument to the [`instanceFor` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore/instanceFor.html).